# What NPCs can you get?

Tags: terraria-mobile

What NPCs can you get on Terreria mobile? I have just started playing. My friend said "I am an expert and have all the NPCs."

Comment: Can't you ask your friend?

Answer (score 1):

Terraria has fantastic wiki resources online that will have this for you:

http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Npc

Here is the complete NPC List that should be accurate for Mobile (I removed the two that were PC only):

- [Guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide)
- [Merchant](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Merchant)
- [Nurse](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nurse)
- [Painter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Painter)
- [Dye Trader](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye_Trader)
- [Demolitionist](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demolitionist)
- [Dryad](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad)
- [Arms Dealer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Arms_Dealer)
- [Party Girl](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Party_Girl)
- [Goblin Tinkerer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Tinkerer)
- [Witch Doctor](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Witch_Doctor)
- [Clothier](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clothier)
- [Mechanic](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Mechanic)

**HARD MODE:**

- [Pirate](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pirate)
- [Truffle](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Truffle)
- [Wizard](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wizard)
- [Steampunker](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker)
- [Cyborg](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cyborg)
- [Santa Claus](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Santa_Claus)